# I try to add a dollar sign within a condition in jQuery but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

I'd like to add a dollar sign after a counter if one of the div has a class .dollar, but it's putting it for all .counter div.

```
$('.counter').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
    $({
        countNum: $this.text()
    }).animate({
        countNum: countTo
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function() {
            if ($('.counter').hasClass('dollar')) {
              $this.text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.floor(this.countNum) + '$'));
            } else {
              $this.text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.floor(this.countNum)));
            }
        },
        complete: function() {
            $this.text(commaSeparateNumber(this.countNum));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what do you mean ? Sorry i'm not a jQuery expert...

Comment: can you please share HTML code plz?